# Remove numbers in section in scribble (latex backend)

Tags: latex, racket, scribble

In scribble, I have a document like:

```
#lang scribble/lncs

@section{First Section}
@section{Second Section}
@subsection{A subsection}
@section{Third Section}
```

And this will get compiled to a document that looks something like:

## 1. First Section

## 2. Second Section

### 2.1 A subsection

## 3. Third Section

How can I remove these numbers so that it looks something more like:

## First Section

## Second Section

### A subsection

## Third Section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `'unnumbered` or `hidden-number` style as [documented in the `para` documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/core.html?q=part#%28def._%28%28lib._scribble%2Fcore..rkt%29._part%29%29).

These two styles have similar, but slightly different uses:

- `'unnumbered` is when there is no number associated with this section. Use this when you do not want to reference a section and want the next section to have the next incremental number.
- `'hidden-number` is when the section does have a number, but it is not shown. This causes the next section to jump up a number, but you can still reference it.

The following code will cause the document to look like you want:

```
#lang scribble/lncs

@section[#:style 'unnumbered]{First Section}
@section[#:style 'unnumbered]{Second Section}
@subsection[#:style 'unnumbered]{A subsection}
@section[#:style 'unnumbered]{Third Section}
```

The document will look something like:

## First Section

## Second Section

### A subsection

## Third Section